# Unifying polykinded quantification variable with tuple kinded type

Tags: haskell, data-kinds, forall, polykinds

I have the following class representing categories where the object class is represented by a kind, and each hom class is represented by a type indexed by types of the aforementioned kind.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, PolyKinds #-}

type Hom o = o -> o -> *

class GCategory (p :: Hom o)
  where
  gid :: p a a
  gcompose :: p b c -> p a b -> p a c
```

a simple example of an instance is:

```
instance GCategory (->)
  where
  gid = id
  gcompose = (.)
```

Now I want to model product categories. As a simple starting point, here's a type modeling the morphisms of a category corresponding to a product of `->` with itself:

```
data Bifunction ab cd
  where
  Bifunction :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> Bifunction '(a, b) '(c, d)
```

here's the corresponding operations:

```
bifunction_id :: Bifunction '(a, a') '(a, a')
bifunction_id = Bifunction id id

bifunction_compose :: Bifunction '(b, b') '(c, c') -> Bifunction '(a, a') '(b, b') -> Bifunction '(a, a') '(c, c')
bifunction_compose (Bifunction f1 g1) (Bifunction f2 g2) = Bifunction (f1 . f2) (g1 . g2)
```

but when I try to stick the operations into an instance of the class:

```
instance GCategory Bifunction
  where
  gid = bifunction_id
  gcompose = bifunction_compose
```

I run into the following issue:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘'(a0, a'0)’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      gid :: forall (a :: (*, *)). Bifunction a a
    at /tmp/ghc-mod29677/Bifunction29676-49.hs:28:3-5
  Expected type: Bifunction a a
    Actual type: Bifunction '(a0, a'0) '(a0, a'0)
• In the expression: bifunction_id
  In an equation for ‘gid’: gid = bifunction_id
  In the instance declaration for ‘GCategory Bifunction’
• Relevant bindings include
    gid :: Bifunction a a
      (bound at /tmp/ghc-mod29677/Bifunction29676-49.hs:28:3)
```

I believe the important part of the message is the following:

```
  Expected type: Bifunction a a
    Actual type: Bifunction '(a0, a'0) '(a0, a'0)
```

specifically that it can't unify the type `forall x y. Bifunction '(x, y) '(x, y)` with the type `forall (a :: (*, *)). Bifunction a a`.

Stripping away most of the domain specific stuff, we're left with the following minimal repro of the problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, PolyKinds, RankNTypes #-}

module Repro where

data Bifunction ab cd
  where
  Bifunction :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> Bifunction '(a, b) '(c, d)

bifunction_id :: Bifunction '(a, a') '(a, a')
bifunction_id = Bifunction id id

bifunction_id' :: Bifunction a a
bifunction_id' = bifunction_id
```

Is there a way I can unify `bifunction_id` with `bifunction_id'` above?

---

An alternative approach I've tried is to use type families, but that still doesn't completely solve the problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, PolyKinds, RankNTypes, TypeFamilies #-}

module Repro where

type family Fst (ab :: (x, y)) :: x
  where
  Fst '(x, y) = x

type family Snd (ab :: (x, y)) :: y
  where
  Fst '(x, y) = y

data Bifunction ab cd = Bifunction (Fst ab -> Fst cd) (Snd cd -> Snd cd)

bifunction_id :: Bifunction '(a, a') '(a, a')
bifunction_id = Bifunction id id

-- This still doesn't work
-- bifunction_id' :: Bifunction a a
-- bifunction_id' = bifunction_id

-- But now I can do this successfully
bifunction_id' :: Bifunction a a
bifunction_id' = Bifunction id id
```

But I don't really understand why this identical expression works, and would rather not have to manage a somewhat non obvious distinction like this throughout the rest of the code.

Comment: Why not just use the `Category` class from `Control.Category`? It's essentially the same (including being polykinded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forall (x :: k) (y :: l). p '(x, y)` is less general than `forall (a :: (k, l)). p a`, mainly because there are things of kind `(k, l)` which are not pairs.

```
type family NotAPair :: () -> () -> () -> (k, l)
```

(Note that the type family has no parameters, it's not the same as `NotAPair (u :: ()) (v :: ()) (w :: ()) :: ()`). If `NotAPair '() '() '() :: (k, l)` were actually a pair `'(,) x y`, then we would have this nonsense: `'(,) ~ NotAPair '()`, `x ~ '()`, `y ~ '()`.

See also Computing with impossible types https://gelisam.blogspot.com/2017/11/computing-with-impossible-types.html

And even if "all things of kind `(k, l)` are pairs", there are different ways to make that fact available in the language. If you make it implicit, so that you could for example implicitly convert a `forall x y. p '(x, y)` into a `forall a. p a`, you may (or may not) make typechecking undecidable. If you make it explicit, you will have to work to write that conversion (that's Coq for example).

Comment: Isn't the decomposition you're doing by turning `NotAPair '() '() '() ~ '(,) x y` into `NotAPair '() ~ '(,)`, `'() ~ x`, `'() ~ y` only valid when we are looking at generative + injective type mappings (which elsewhere are called "matchable")? As far as I understand the type system doesn't bother to decompose things like this anyway when faced with a type family instead of a type constructor, so you don't end up with the absurd conclusion you're illustrating. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: The point is precisely that `NotAPair` is creating a generative type mapping out of thin air.

Answer (score 1):

In `gid @Bifunction`'s definition, you have a type `a :: (Type, Type)`. `(,)` only has one constructor, so we can deduce that there must exist `x :: Type` and `y :: Type` such that `a ~ '(x, y)`. However, this reasoning is not expressible in Haskell. Basically, when you have a type-level pair (something of type `(i, j)`) in Haskell, you can not assume that it is actually a pair (something of form `'(x, y)`). This causes your code to break: you have `Bifunction id id :: forall x y. Bifunction '(x, y) '(x, y)`, but you need a `Bifunction a a`, and you just do not have a typing rule that lets you assume that `a ~ (x, y)` for some `x`, `y`. When you use the alternate, weird definition of `Bifunction`, then you get `Bifunction id id :: forall a. Bifunction a a` (because that's the return type of the constructor), and it works basically because `Fst` and `Snd` are "partial" functions.

I would personally just add "all pairs are actually pairs" as an axiom.

```
data IsTup (xy :: (i, j)) =
    forall (x :: i) (y :: j). xy ~ '(x, y) => IsTup
-- could also write
-- data IsTup (xy :: (i, j)) where
--     IsTup :: forall (x :: i) (y :: j). IsTup '(x, y)
isTup :: forall xy. IsTup xy
isTup = unsafeCoerce IsTup

bifunction_id :: Bifunction '(a, x) '(a, x)
bifunction_id = Bifunction id id
bifunction_compose :: Bifunction '(b, y) '(c, z) -> Bifunction '(a, x) '(b, y) -> Bifunction '(a, c) '(x, z)
bifunction_compose (Bifunction fl fr) (Bifunction gl gr) = Bifunction (fl . gl) (fr . gr)

instance GCategory Bifunction where
   gid :: forall a. Bifunction a a -- necessary to bind a
   -- usage of axiom: isTup produces a "proof" that a is actually a pair and
   -- matching against IsTup "releases" the two components and the equality 
   gid | IsTup <- isTup @a = bifunction_id
   gcompose :: forall a b c. Bifunction b c -> Bifunction a b -> Bifunction a c
   gcompose
     | IsTup <- isTup @a, IsTup <- isTup @b, IsTup <- isTup @c
     = bifunction_compose
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I don't understand the "Your original signatures were too restricted" comment though. It seems like your signatures are the same as mine, just with differently named skolems.

Comment: I think you misread the type signatures in the question. It's `bifunction_id :: Bifunction '(a, a') '(a, a')`, not `bifunction_id :: Bifunction '(a, a) '(a, a)`. Similar for the composition operation. Changing `a` to `x` and `a'` to `y` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for teaching me a new technique, I've often needed to "magically" introduce constraints into scope.